# Activate Label and Link with one click

Tags: css, html, radio-button

I want to make one click activate both, label and link, because my menu works with links and moves to the correct point of the page, but the label has to activate the button which makes the content enlarge and close the menu. 
I tried it with:

```
<label for="thebutton"><a href="#boxwithcontent">Click me</a></label>
```

But that only activates the link or the label (if the label area is bigger). See what i mean [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0d58f3eo/).

Probably the hardest problem will be that I don´t want to use jquery.

I think a possibility would either be to control the scroll via radio buttons or control the radio button via the link, but I can´t find any way to do that.

Thanks for any efforts

Tim

Comment: Nesting two (or more) interactive elements together is problematic. I don't *think* there is pure CSS solution to your problem, you'd have to use some JavaScript code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your intention but you might just try something like this instead.

Using your HTML with a quickie edit;

```
<label for="magicbutton">Click Me</label>
<input id="magicbutton" type="checkbox" onclick='window.location.assign("#field")'/>

<div id="field"><p>
magic text
</p></div>
```

and your CSS with a quickie edit;

```
#field{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
}

input {float: left;}

input#magicbutton:checked ~ #field{
    display:block;
}
```

...and a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L2ywu2ta/

I didn't change much, hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: @Aziz hey he only said no jquery :P

Comment: works but sorry I thought that JavaScript and JQuery are the same. is sth similar possible without any JavaScript. Otherwise I will use a note to the user that JavaScript helps improving navigation.

Comment: @TimVahlbrock JS is a language, JQuery is a (heavy) library. The user wouldn't even notice since JS is already built into whatever they're using without needing JQuery. I hope that's a decent explanation. Basically if it does HTML5, it does JS....For it to do JQuery though the library has to be added.

Comment: @ Chris W. so JS is standard included into browsers and the user doesn´t have to install sth to use it?

Comment: @TimVahlbrock I'm not sure what "sth" refers to but yes, you will be hard pressed to find a browser on any platform or device that doesn't support basic JS components out of the box by default standard. :)

Comment: @TimVahlbrock no worries, glad you found a remedy. I'm still curious what "sth" is though lol.

Comment: @ChrisW. he meant to say *something*... "user doesn't have to install something to use it"

Answer (score 0):

Technically not a link, but with some styling it might boil down to the same:

```
<form action="#boxwithcontent" method="get">
  <label>test<button type="submit">Click me</button></label>
</form>
```

If you have several of them, you might use one form, and use the `formaction` attribute on the button...